# Groovy multi-line string stripIndent() with interpolated string from `join("\n")` array

Tags: groovy

When I use the results of a `.join("\n")` array in a multi-line string then `stripIndent()` doesn't appear to work:

```
def list = [ 'one', 'two' ]
def listAsString = list.join("\n")

def string = """\
  First line for listAsString

  $listAsString

  Last line
""".stripIndent()
```

Note: I am using the escaped first line.

This produces:

```
  First line for listAsString

  one
two

  Last line
```

Instead of

```
First line for listAsString

one
two

Last line
```

*However* if I use it with a normal variable it works OK:

```
def exampleVar = 'fred'

def string2 = """\
  First line for plain list
  
  $exampleVar

  Last line
""".stripIndent()
```

Produces:

```
First line for plain list

fred

Last line
```

This is as I would expect.

Is there something special I need to do if `join()`ing an array for use in a multi-line string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straight from the javadoc:

```
Strips leading spaces from every line in a CharSequence. 
The line with the least number of leading spaces determines the number to remove.
```

So your join should insert also 2 or whatever number spaces to match the minimal ident:

```
def list = [ 'one', 'two' ]
def listAsString = list.join "\n  "
    
def string = """\
  First line for listAsString

  $listAsString

  Last line
""".stripIndent()

assert string == '''\
First line for listAsString

one
two

Last line
'''
```

Comment: Thanks, your example works; I did read the javadoc but I misinterpreted (I think many people do this based on my search results). My confusion is that I escaped the first line (`"""\\`) so I thought the minimal indent was thus 0 so it would remove all leading spaces (regardless of what they are) to match the 0. 

What it actually does, I think, is remove 0 *up to* "minimum space found". So if the minimum space found is also 0 it doesn't do anything. If the minimum space found is 1 it'll remove 1 space (thus if I have something indented by 2 it'll end up with 1 space indentation). And so on.